# How to change cursor position to a picturebox location in VB

Tags: vb.net, cursor, picturebox

i think the title is pretty clear but i'll try to get more into it.

so i created a game where you use the mouse to play, it's like the game labirynth. you can't touch the walls or you lose.

when i start the level i want the cursor to appear in it's starting position, which is a red picturebox, but i dont know how to...

here is the code i used:

Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(679, 650)

as you can see there is a massive problem about this code.

the location where the cursor appears is actuallt dependent of the resolution of the screen.

for example: with my monitor resolution, the location (679, 650) is right on top of the picturebox i need it to appear on. but if you have a different resolution on your monitor it will appear on a different place...

i need to actually make it appear on top of the picturebox.

i wish i could be clearer than this :(

Comment: Don't do that at all!!! Taking control over the mouse will irritate the user in a huge way. Imagine the user try's to close the window by moving the mouse to the X on the top right of the window, but the labyrinth has walls all around the contents of the window. How about dragging a circle thru the labirynth and if the circle touches a wall, the circle will be set to the starting position.

Answer (score 1):

you can set your mouse location after taking the value of your picture position.

```
x=picture1.left
y=picture1.top
Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(x+somevalue,y+somevalue)
```

Comment: This is the code im using:


Dim x As Integer
        Dim y As Integer
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(Application.StartupPath + "\buttonclick.wav")
        Me.Hide()
        Form2.Show()
        MessageBox.Show("Não toques nas paredes!", "Nível 1", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        x = PictureBox6.Left
        y = PictureBox6.Top
        Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(x + 1, y + 1)


now the cursor ends up out of the game window, i need it to start on top of the picturebox

Comment: To which form Picture box belongs?

Comment: in vb6 if you take left of some object it will give you the value relatively to which it is reside.For example if your pictureBox is in a frame then left of the picture will give you the value by considering the frame,not the form.I think you are messing up with this kind of things